# Fitting a curve and finding knee for a HISTOGRAM

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, plotly, curve-fitting

I have a decreasing histogram which shows the counts of a metric starting from 1 with a very high peak there and decreasing constantly till zero at around 15. I want to find the "knee"/"elbow" to the curve of this decrease, but most answers here are for scatter plots. I know I can hackingly turn my histogram to a scatter plot, but more neatly, how can I fit a curve to a histogram and find parameters related to that curve? Thanks.

I work with pandas and I mainly plot with plotly.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the unbinned raw data?

Comment: ...and actually some code of yours showing what you have done up to now would be cool...with respect to the "how to ask"

Comment: I'm not even sure what to share because I havent done anything as far as fitting goes. I'm asking HOW to do it because I have no idea. In regards to the first comment, the raw data is confidential. I can share the histogram but its basically a concave decreasing histogram plot, so pick your generic one.... I just wanna know how one can fit a curve to a given histogram